# How do I run linux commands WHM VPS

Tags: linux, command, vps

I'd like to check the MySQL & PHP Versions that are running on my Linux VPS. I don't anything about this stuff.

php -m

mysql -v

I've found these commands above to run, but I don't physically know where to input them? Where's the command line? Sorry if this is stupid.

I have access to my WHM, root, cPanel etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view the MySQL and PHP version from cPanel using the following steps.

1. Log into cPanel.
2. Under General Information on the right panel, click Server Information.
   [image: General Information View]
3. Under the Item column, find PHP & MySQL Version.
4. In the Detail column, note the version number.
   [image: Server Information View]

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to ssh into the machine, which will show you a bash prompt where you can input your commands.

If you can't ssh because it is just a rented php server, you can write a script in php to execute your commands, also php has a `phpinfo();` command which is useful.